# I want to scroll down to the body of text using textView which is clickable

Tags: java, android

I have an activity which has a few Headings or Topic Titles and then when you scroll down it shows the Description of each Title. I want these titles to display these description whenever they are clicked, so as to save the user from the hassle.
I cannot share my .xml or .java files, as the information inside it is too big. Any help is appreciated.
I am aware of onClickListeners but I am not that familiar with Android to make it work.

Comment: please include in your question what you have tried in terms of code.

Comment: Nothing yet, as I have said I'm new to Android Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your content inside a `ScrollView` and when the title is clicked do as below in order to programmatically scroll to the desired position. Replace `SCROLL_HEIGHT` with your suitable height (it's in pixels).

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
           scrollView.scrollTo(0, SCROLL_HEIGHT);              
    }
});
```